# Receive data using python program from a php page where page is not echoed any content and has post data

Tags: php, python, post, python-requests

I have a php page [`page1.php`] having one form which has one text box. In this I am posting the data to another php page [`page2.php`] using method of post. But in `page2` i am not `echoing` anything.

Now I need to run one `python` program where i'll be given `page2.php` as the `url="localhost:project/page2.php"`. Here I need to print the content of the text box which has been posted from `page1`.

I am using requests library and i have tried the following code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost/project/page2.php'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

But the output is blank since in `page2` i have not display the content using `echo  $_POST['text'];`
Is it possible to get the data without displaying any content in `page2.`

Comment: Best way to do that is to have a callback url from python and do a cURL in php to pass your data back to python.

Comment: @ACD Sorry I could not understand the solution. Can u explain with a small example...

Comment: you need `requests.post(url,data=data)`?  I am trying to understande the connection between page1 and page2. Can you explain again what you want to do?